# How to access dataset from custom component linked with Live Bindings?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3, firemonkey-fm2, livebindings

I am creating my own DBGrid that is derived from TMSFMXGrid. How can I find out which dataset is linked to this grid, if it is linked using Live Bindings? In design time you can see in object inspector property LiveBinding, but is not accessible in run time. Otherwise I will have to publish my own property, where you could define used dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of searching, I had found out this solution.

```
function GetDataSet: TDataSet;
var
  obj: TColumnDescObject;
  dts: TBaseLinkingBindSource;
  ds: TDataSet;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if ColumnDescList.Count > 0 then
  begin
    obj := TColumnDescObject(ColumnDescList.Items[0]);
    if Assigned(obj) then
    begin
      dts := obj.ColumnDesc.DataSource;
      if Assigned(dts) then
      begin
        if dts is TCustomBindSourceDB then
        begin
          ds := (dts as TCustomBindSourceDB).DataSet;
          if Assigned(ds) then
          begin
            Result := ds;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```